# No Hard Disk found Message on Boot up, but everything works fine, SSD

Tags: hard-drive, bios, sata

I just built a computer, with a SSD Hard Drive.  I also have 2 other hard drives in the computer which are regular SATA.

Upon boot up, I get an error that states, "No Hard Disk Found" but in reality everything works fine right after that message disappears.

What might be causing this and if it's a BIOS setting I need to change to not get that message what setting might that be?

**Okay hardware info:**

- Asus P6X58D PREMIUM motherboard
- Kingston 128 GB SSD
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 465 PNY Edition
- Corsair 12 GB DDR3 1600 Mhz Ram
- Windows 7 Ultimate

anything else i can tell you, i will, just ask

Comment: A little info about your hardware would be nice.

Comment: @bobby, done, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [same question at extremeoverclocking.com](http://forums.extremeoverclocking.com/showthread.php?t=342104) this is not directly related with your harddrives. The motherboard is looking for [SATA Rev. 3 (aka SATA 6 Gb)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_Revision_3.0_.28SATA_6_Gb.2Fs.29) drives, but can not find any (most likely because you don't have any).

You can simply turn turn it off in BIOS.