# No Hard Disk found Message on Boot up, SSD Map: Cannot find required map name

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, power-supply, hardware-failure

I had this issue ["Motherboard saying that it cannot find required map name."](https://Motherboard%20saying%20that%20it%20cannot%20find%20required%20map%20name.)

The referenced approach included the description:

```
So this is what is showed:
EFI Shell Version 2.31 [4.633]
Current running mode 1.1.2
Map: Cannot find required map name

Press Esc in 5 seconds to skip startup.nsh, any other key to continue

shell id>
```

Also:

> After you reset the cmos, please enter the bios and check setting, esp
> sata mode since the default might not be what it was when you
> installed windows. And windows wont boot if its in the wrong mode.

And:

> i had the same problem with one of my computer. i have done this
> resetting the cmos. even do the default setting for the bios. change
> plug from sata 1 up to sata 6. check the power plug in tight. but of
> no success. this error still the same. and when i enter bios after
> exiting this error i notice that the setting from sata1 up to sata6 is
> null. i forgot what it says but i think that the computer doesn't read
> the sata. i have change the sata cable but still the same. any one can
> figure out what is the problem of my computer?

So what was going on with my computer?  I tried the recommended techniques, but they did not seem to help.

Are there any additional suggestions?  This is because this issue is a very popular one, one that comes up first with a browser search.  But it is not completely responded to, leaving the computer-user without an adequate solution in many cases.

I am looking for different answers and comments that address the problem.  I am posting this question here because from this [Stack Exchange Reference to the Question "Where do I ask hardware-related questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76731/where-do-i-ask-hardware-related-questions), it states:

> You can ask questions regarding computer hardware over at
> SuperUser.com. If your question concerns server hardware, there is an
> amount of crossover with Serverfault.com.
>
> Update As of 2018, Hardware Recommendations is in beta.

Thank you community for help **fully answering this question**.  Since the existing answer seems incomplete and it ranks first in the web-search, it seems any additional contributions should be beneficial to the entire community.

I found this [similar question on the Stack Exchange Super User Site, ""](https://superuser.com/questions/175398/no-hard-disk-found-message-on-boot-up-but-everything-works-fine-ssd), but it is describing a different situation it seems and has an entirely different solution for the most part as the answer posted there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is kind of difficult, because the computer BIOS just dumps out to a shell with a cryptic message:

```
EFI Shell Version 2.31 [4.633]
Current running mode 1.1.2
Map: Cannot find required map name

Press Esc in 5 seconds to skip startup.nsh, any other key to continue

shell id>
```

Typing "ls" also does not list any drives.

The thing to look into carefully in BIOS if the drives are actually listed (as active).  Check the power supply connections, especially if the power supply has been recently replaced.

Sometimes when the power supply is replaced, only the cables to the computer are connected, and the power supply still does not connect to the SSD or HD.  Then the HD does not show up in the BIOS menu.  But, strangely enough, the computer still boots up to the "EFI Shell Version 2.31 [4.633] prompt", which is cryptic.

In the end, I checked the power-supply.  The power adapter connector to the SSD was no connected, and there were no other boot devices.

After I connected the connector from the new power supply (the old power supply was connected before), then the drive showed up in the BIOS listing of SATA devices, and everything booted and worked fine!